# Customed ExpandableListView can't change height

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my expandable listview, I have group & child layout: 
I can't set size of height by android:layout_height="@dimen/title_indicator_heigh"
How can I change height of them ?

- group:

``` ``<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/title_indicator_heigh" > ```

```
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/img_group_item"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/slidingmenu_indicator_width"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingmenu_indicator_heigh"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
     android:contentDescription="@string/description"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_narrow" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_group_item"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/slidingmenu_group_margin_left"
     android:text="@string/menu_category"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
     android:textIsSelectable="false"
     android:textSize="@dimen/slidingmenu_item_group_text_size" />
```

`

- Child

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/slidingmenu_item_child_heigh">`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_child_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/slidingmenu_group_margin_left"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="@string/title_cate_cong_nghe"
    android:textColor="@color/black_menu_text"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/slidingmenu_item_child_text_size" />
```

Comment: Have You tried android:minHeight ?

Comment: No, I haven't
But when I add   android:paddingTop="11dp", the height seems higher.
I don't know why